# data feed automation using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody please guide me with logic flow . I dont want the code , I'm looking for some guidance and then I can write code myself.

Thanks in advnace

Comment: Do you have a way of letting excel know where the different data should go? Is it always this pattern?

Comment: 1) get a reference to the source Range 2) move data to a Variant array 3) create another  VA of the same size 4) run a loop mapping the two arrays 5) place the result array on the destination sheet

Comment: Where is ColE - did you hide it ?

Comment: @macro did the logic flow I proposed in my comment not wor for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    With Ws
        .Cells.Clear
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Cells(i, i) = "DATA" & i
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
Sub TransData()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim y As Integer, x As Integer

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    Set toWs = Sheets(2)

    vDB = Ws.UsedRange

    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To c)
    For i = 1 To r
        For j = 1 To c
            y = r - i + 1
            x = c - j + 1
            vR(y, j) = vDB(y, x)
        Next j
    Next i
    With toWs
        .Range("a1").Resize(r, c) = vR
    End With
End Sub
```